# MailChimp Double Optin API not sending conf. email

Tags: mailchimp

I've created an express backend and I want to setup double optin. My code already works if I set the status to 'subscribed', but changing this to 'pending' does not result in the confirmation email being sent.

I have also updated a list for enabling double optin (and created a 2nd audience to test as well, same result).

I upgraded my mailchimp account from free to a paid option, and it's still not sending the confirmation email or adding the email at all in the audience (the code is responding with successful, though)?

Here's the pertinent part of the code:

```js
    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: 'pending'
            }
        ]
    }

    const postData = JSON.stringify(data);

    const options = {
        url: 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/mylistid',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'auth mykey'
        },
        body: postData
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, never mind. After what seemed to be 20+ minutes, I finally received the confirmation emails. The contact won't show up in MailChimp until a user confirms their email, so that's why it wasn't showing up in the MC UI.

Pretty disappointing it took that long for a confirmation email to be sent out. That will result in people forgetting to confirm -- hopefully that was just an exception and not the norm in the response time.